# Center text on productpages

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

how can i center all the text on my product pages.

Now it's left lined. See image attached.
[image]

And is it possible, to place the code over here:
[image]

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: Yea, i know that website.. But can you tell me what the code is? I don't know which parts i have to code. That's why i'm asking it you guy's.

Comment: I don't know what markup your theme has. It's hard to tell from an image. =D Check the class around your html text and target it with css.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: @sukumar Gorai http://schoenen-data.eu/catalog/category/view/s/dames/id/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these 2 below lines and everything will be centered for this page:

```
.catalog-category-view li.item.product.product-item-info.product-item.col-lg-3.col-md-3.col-sm-4.col-xs-6 {
    text-align: center;
}

.catalog-category-view li.item.product.product-item-info.product-item.col-lg-3.col-md-3.col-sm-4.col-xs-6 .price-box + div{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You need to add more class before those lines if need more nested or for particular pages.

Comment: The custom settings is for the whole magento theme, so this code doesn't work.

Comment: Can you check the updated answer? This should work only work for Category pages.

Comment: Thanks for ya fast reply, but it does't works:
http://schoenen-data.eu/catalog/category/view/s/dames/id/4/

Comment: Your css is not loaded to that page? Check it by view source its not showing anywhere? I have try to search by .catalog-category-view but nothing found. If its not working like this then add the above css to your any phtml and test. This is not a good practice to do so.

Comment: I think it was a cache issue, it's working now! Thanks for ya fast reply and your patience.

Comment: Happy to help! Can you please upvote?